# My touchpad malfunctions after running for a while

Tags: linux, touchpad

I have 2-finger scrolling set up on my touchpad, using GNOME settings. After running my laptop for a while (several hours), such scrolling is no longer functional, and the touchpad itself is rather unstable (barely usable). Here's the output from syslog:

```
Nov 15 21:07:06 tshepang kernel: [40639.175677] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio4/input0 lost sync at byte 4
Nov 15 21:07:06 tshepang kernel: [40639.177708] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio4/input0 lost sync at byte 1
Nov 15 21:07:06 tshepang kernel: [40639.191630] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio4/input0 - driver resynched.
Nov 15 21:07:07 tshepang kernel: [40639.503288] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio4/input0 lost sync at byte 1
Nov 15 21:07:07 tshepang kernel: [40639.505326] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio4/input0 lost sync at byte 1
Nov 15 21:07:07 tshepang kernel: [40639.507310] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio4/input0 lost sync at byte 1
Nov 15 21:07:07 tshepang kernel: [40639.509479] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio4/input0 lost sync at byte 1
Nov 15 21:07:07 tshepang kernel: [40639.511280] psmouse.c: TouchPad at isa0060/serio4/input0 lost sync at byte 1
Nov 15 21:07:07 tshepang kernel: [40639.511285] psmouse.c: issuing reconnect request
Nov 15 21:07:07 tshepang kernel: [40640.198742] Unable to query Synaptics hardware.
```

I'm on Debian Unstable, currently with Linux 3.1. The problem is reproducible with Linux 3.0. I haven't tried any other kernel. Reloading the psmouse module (`sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse`) doesn't help, forcing me to reboot the machine. I'm wondering if this could be a hardware problem.

Comment: This might be a hardware issue, but if you have a look at some parameters for the touchpad *device*, under `/sys` or `/proc`, you'd probably find some means to trigger a reset of the touchpad (that should get you roughly the equivalent of rebooting, without rebooting). So first, find out the device path, using `lsusb`, `lspci` etc.

Comment: FWIW I no longer have access to the laptop on which I experienced this issue.